# PHP Image Cant Make background transparent

Tags: php, png, gd, transparent, alpha

I've got a snippet of code,

The idea of it is to create a transparent canvas to a defined height/width, so I'm able to place either a jpg/png/gif in there.

However if it places a PNG in there with transparency it needs to preserve the transparency for it.

This is a sample of the code

```
    header("Content-type: image/png");

    $canvas = imagecreatetruecolor($maxWidth, $maxHeight);
    $image = $_GET['file'];
    $leftOffset = ($maxWidth / 2) - ($width / 2);
    $topOffset = ($maxHeight / 2) - ($height / 2);
    $quality    = (isset($_GET['quality'])) ? (int) ceil($_GET['quality'] / 10) : ceil($DEFAULT_QUALITY / 10);

    $quality = $quality == 10 ? 9 : $quality; 

    switch($mime){
        case "image/jpeg":
            $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($image);
            $red = imagecolorallocate($canvas, 0, 255, 0);
            imagecolortransparent($canvas, $red);
            imagefill($canvas, 0, 0 ,$red);
        break;
        case "image/gif":
            $image = imagecreatefromgif($image);
        break;
        case "image/png":
            $background = imagecolorallocate($canvas, 255, 0, 0);
            imagecolortransparent($canvas, $background);
            imagealphablending($canvas, false);
            imagesavealpha($canvas, true); 
            $image = imagecreatefrompng($image);
        break;
    }

    imagecopyresampled($canvas, $image, $leftOffset, $topOffset, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width, $width);
    imagepng($canvas, null, $quality);
    imagedestroy($canvas);
```

However the problem is, the canvas remains black, whilst the box area around the image is transparent.

The image below demonstrates this, the Lime green colour is the body {background: lime;} so you're able to see the transparent areas

[image]

I tried using a transparent colour after the imagecreatetruecolor

```
$red = imagecolorallocate($canvas, 255, 0, 0);
imagecolortransparent($canvas, $red);
imagefill($canvas, 0, 0 ,$red);
```

If the .png has a fade effect, it gets a nasty red glow around it where the colour is no longer exactly 255, 0, 0

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Have you seen my answer?

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you!

```
<?
$image = "your_image.png";

$image_info = getimagesize($image);
$width = $image_info[0];
$height = $image_info[1];
$mime_type = $image_info["mime"];
$maxWidth = 250;
$maxHeight = 250;
$quality = 9;

header("Content-type: $mime_type");

$canvas = imagecreatetruecolor($maxWidth, $maxHeight);
imagealphablending($canvas, false);
$background = imagecolorallocatealpha($canvas, 255, 255, 255, 127);
imagefilledrectangle($canvas, 0, 0, $maxWidth, $maxHeight, $background);
imagealphablending($canvas, true);

$leftOffset = ($maxWidth / 2) - ($width / 2);
$topOffset = ($maxHeight / 2) - ($height / 2);

switch($mime_type)
{
    case "image/jpeg":
        //JPG code
        break;
    case "image/gif":
        //GIF code
        break;
    case "image/png":
        $new_image = imagecreatefrompng($image);
        imagecopyresampled($canvas, $new_image, $leftOffset, $topOffset, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width, $height);
        imagealphablending($canvas, true);        
        imagesavealpha($canvas, true);
        imagepng($canvas, null, $quality);
        imagedestroy($canvas);        
        break;
}
?>
```

Comment: Nice one fella, been looking for this solution for an hour.